# Xcode asking me "who you are" (screenshot)

Tags: xcode, macos, swift

I started programing in xcode and when i launch it, xcode ask me "who you are". Does anybody know what is necessary to do? Thanks!

screenshot:
[image]

Comment: That's not xcode, it's git asking you who you are. You have to run the suggested command from the terminal, entering the requested data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Xcode includes integrated support for Git. Your screen shot is Git asking for you to set your user name and email address (which is arbitrary, not some official Git login) which it uses to sign your commits. When you create a new Xcode project, you can de-select The "Source Control" option if you're not a Git user--see attached screen shot. When you start working on a "real" project, I suggest you learn the basics of Git for revision control of your project, such as  adding files, making commits, and rolling back changes you might make that break things. Every time you add some piece of functionality and ensure it's working, make a Git commit. Then you can always roll back, or grab files, from previous known working checkpoints. This is all kept on your local machine, and then of course you have the choice to push to a remote repo such as Github.

[image: Git Source Control seletion]

To fix the problem, execute the two commands listed in the error message from the command line:

```
$ git config --global user.name "John Doe"
$ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

[Info on setting up Git](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup)